# Proving inequality given extreme and integral values

Tags: integration

Let two continuous functions $f,g: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$. If $m$ is the minimum value of $f$ and $M$ is the maximum value of $g$ and $$\int^1_0 f(x) dx = \int^1_0 g(x) dx = \frac 1 2 (M+m)$$ prove that $$\int^1_0 f(x)g(x) dx \leq \frac 1 2 (m^2 + M^2)$$

What I have tried:

1. Apply MVT at $[0,1]$ for the antiderivative of $f$ to obtain $m \leq M$
2. Reforming the inequality to 
   $$\int^1_0 2f(t)g(t)dt - \bigg ( \int^1_0 (f(t) + g(t) )dt \bigg)^2 \leq 0$$ in order to study $$h(x) = \int^x_0 2f(t)g(t)dt - \bigg ( \int^x_0 (f(t) + g(t) )dt \bigg)^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows: write $$fM-mM-fg+mg=(f-m)(M-g)\geq 0\Rightarrow fg\leq fM+mg-mM,$$ therefore, after integrating, $$\int_0^1fg\leq M\frac{M+m}{2}+m\frac{M+m}{2}-mM=\frac{M^2+m^2}{2}.$$